# Specific Profile Access to Create or Edit in Account Related Contacts in Validation Rule or Triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, community, salesforcedx, validation-rule

Iam trying to create a validation rule for specific profile access to create or edit in account related contacts in validation rule

my code in validation rule  at account object

**AND(
NOT( $Profile.Name  =  'Marketing'),
AND( ISNEW(), ISPICKVAL(Assigned_Status__c, 'Press')))**

Comment: If you want to control "Contacts", you'll need to create the validation rule in the Contact Object. Furthermore, this will control creation and edits, but it won't control deletions. (And don't forget to add the System Administrator in case you want them to be able to do so)

Comment: Hi Sergio Alcocer
   thanks for your prompt reply,                                                                                                                          I have my picklist field  **Assigned_Status__c**  in the **Account Object** and I have to control the Account Related contacts ,As you said  how to handle this particular picklist Assigned_Status__c  in the contact object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on the comments, you'll need to control that on Contact level.
Something like the code below should be ok

```
AND(
    $Profile.Name != 'Marketing',
    ISPICKVAL(Account.Assigned_Status__c, 'Press')
)
```

Keep in mind that as I said on the comments, this will prevent anyone from creating / editing Contacts with that status, but it will not prevent someone to delete them.

Also consider if you want to add the System Administration as exception (besides Marketing)

Comment: Thank you Sergio Alcocer,Its working